# Computing the homology of torus (or elliptic curve) via $\mathbb{C}^*/q^\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to understand the homology of the torus (or elliptic curve) $\mathbb{T}$ by identifying it with $\mathbb{C}^*/q^\mathbb{Z}$, where $0<|q|<1$ and $q^n$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^*$ just by multiplication. This is the exponential of the "ordinary" representation $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\tau$ where $q=\exp(2\pi i\tau)$. Then
$H_1(\mathbb{T},\mathbb{C})$ is generated by $e_1$ and $e_2$:

$e_1$ is the pushforward of $(1/2\pi i)\sigma_n$ where $\sigma_n\in H_1(\mathbb{C}^*,\mathbb{C})$ is the $n$-th clockwise loop based at $1$;

$e_2$ is the pushforard of a path in $\mathbb{C}^*$ connecting $1$ and $q$.

The claim is $e_1$ is independent of the choice $i$ and $e_2$ is canonical modulo $\mathbb{C} e_1$. I'm wondering how to show this claim is true. (I think if one can prove this by de Rham comparison and compute the integral of the invariant differentail form $\omega$ along different $\sigma_n$'s, but it seems too overkill and complicate.)

Comment: I don't know what the "i-th clockwise loop" means. Which loop is that?

Comment: @DanAsimov It just means go around the origin $i$ times.

Comment: So your e_1 is defined to depend on the index i ?  (And do I see an i = √-1 and the index i in the same sentence?  Not the best idea.)

Comment: @DanAsimov Thanks, I edited the question. Yes, my question is how you can show the independence of the index.